# Why SQL Server replication related jobs do not show up under the jobs folder in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, replication

I found some SQL Server replication-related jobs that do not show up under the jobs folder in SSMS. Can anybody explain why this is, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In replication their are 3 Database/Servers you have:

1. Publisher  : where the data comes from
2. Distribution  : handles tracking and packaging of data to be sent to the subscriber
3. Subscriber  : receives the data

Depending on the type of replication you have setup, the replication jobs may be running at a different location than you expect, ie:

Under Pull replication, there will be jobs running on the Subscriber to pull the data from the distribution database vs Push replication, the job will be running on the Distribution server.

For more info see [MSDN: Replication Agents Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152501.aspx)